# Page opens up blank, html script not working

Tags: html

I have my domain https://instamemories.tk to be redirected to my other link, but the page just shows up blank?  Why isnt my page showing up? i clearly have a code written there but the screen is just blank. The other link that im having it redirect to is: http://www.imxprs.com/free/bowxtoxthexomega/instamemories if that helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <title>instamemories.tk</title>
    <meta name="description" content="instamemories.tk">
    <meta name="keywords" content="instamemories.tk">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-23441223-3']);
        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
        _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        (function() { var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>
  </head>
  <frameset rows="*">
    <frame frameborder=0 src="http://www.imxprs.com/free/bowxtoxthexomega/instamemories" name="dot_tk_frame_content" scrolling="auto" noresize>
  </frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: That second link looks like a phishing attempt

Comment: check the url you have set on iFrame src.

Comment: I feel like the the link I'm redirecting it to would look exactly the same as the website tho? I completely took out the html public frameset and still nothing. @RoshanBhumbra

Comment: ^^^^^^^^ @Ashot